# need checkboxes for a list using Django form

Tags: django-forms, django-templates, django-views

```
forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import VendorApplication, VendorAppWorkFlow
import MySQLdb as mdb
from django.forms.fields import DateField, ChoiceField, MultipleChoiceField
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect, CheckboxSelectMultiple
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget


con = mdb.connect('', '', '', '');
cursor1 = con.cursor()
cursor1.execute("select * from vendorapp_sharetable;")
columns = cursor1.description
num_fields = len(cursor1.description)
field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor1.description]

class CheckForm(forms.Form):
    for index in range(num_fields):
       field_names[index] = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label=field_names[index])
```

I want to add field_names values in `forms.py` to checkbox list without choices or how can I iterate them in choices to have `checkboxMultiselect widget`. As the count of `field_names` varies in my application am facing difficulty to add them to choices and use checkbox widget.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor1.description]

choices = [(x, y) for (x, y) in enumerate (field_names)]

class CheckForm (forms.Form):
    fields = forms.CheckboxMultiSelect (choices = choices, required = False)
```